# What Manga chapter is Episode 414 of Naruto Shippuden from?

Tags: naruto

I want to start reading the manga Naruto Shippuden, but I would rather start reading from the last episode that was aired (currently episode 414). Do you know which chapter that episode (episode 414) would be?

Answer (score 1):

The next episode ["The Two Mangekyo"(416)](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/The_Two_Mangeky%C5%8D) is parallel to [Two Mangekyō (chapter 666)](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Two_Mangeky%C5%8D) from the manga. So you can start with chapter 666.